# Nested models and parent validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I've got two models. 
- `Parent` **has_many** `Children`;
- `Parent` **accepts_nested_attributes_for** `Children`;

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :children, :presence => true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I use validation to validate presence of children for every parent, so I can't save parent without children.

```
parent = Parent.new :name => "Jose"
parent.save
#=> false
parent.children_attributes = [{:name => "Pedro"}, {:name => "Emmy"}]
parent.save
#=> true
```

validation works. Then we will destroy children via `_destroy` attribute:

```
parent.children_attributes = {"0" => {:id => 0, :_destroy => true}}
parent.save
#=> true !!!
parent.reload.children
#=> []
```

so I can destroy all children via nested forms and validation will pass.

Actually that happens because after I delete child from my parent via `_delete`, children method still returns destroyed object before I reload it, so validation passed:

```
parent.children_attributes = {"0" => {:id => 0, :_destroy => true}}
parent.save
#=> true !!!
parent.children
#=> #<Child id:1 ...> # It's actually deleted
parent.reload.children
#=> []
```

Is it bug?

What is the question. The question is best solution to repair it. My approach is to add before_destroy filter to `Child` to check if it is last one. But it makes system complicated.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This will probably work for you, but I have a feeling there's a much better answer out there. It sounds like a bug to me.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :must_have_children

  def must_have_children
    if children.empty? || children.all?(&:marked_for_destruction?)
      errors.add(:base, 'Must have at least one child')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: nevertheless it's better then validating on `Child` side :) thanks

Comment: This validation method is still required as of Rails 3.0.6

Comment: You don't need `children.empty? or ` part because `children.all?` always returns `true` for empty collections

Comment: Quick one liner : `errors.add(:base, 'Must have at least one child') if children.all?(&:marked_for_destruction?)`. Thanks for this !

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. Acording to the documentation

> Validates that the specified
>   attributes are not blank (as defined
>   by Object#blank?)

and `validates :children, :presence => true` is just the the same. The documentation doesn't say what happens if you try to use it on an association. You should use custom validation using `validate`.

Using `validates_presence_of` on `has_many` association calls `blank?` on association `children`, which is an object of class Array. Since the `blank?` is not defined for an `Array`, it fires `method_missing` which is caught inside Rails. Usually it do what you wants but I found it fails in Rails 3.1rc and Ruby 1.8.7 in a really awful way: it silently reverts the changes of associated records. It took me a couple of hours to find out what's happening.

Comment: Actually the problem because it vaidates presence of children BEFORE removing children. So we should check if children are `marked_for_destruction?`