# Rails - Validate Presence Of Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have a model A that has a "has_many" association to another model B.  I have a business requirement that an insert into A requires at least 1 associated record to B.  Is there a method I can call to make sure this is true, or do I need to write a custom validation?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use `validates_presence_of` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  validates_presence_of :bs
end
```

or just `validates`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  validates :bs, :presence => true
end
```

But there is a bug with it if you will use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `:allow_destroy => true`: [Nested models and parent validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144527/nested-models-and-parent-validation). In this topic you can find solution.

Answer (score 18):

-------- Rails 4 ------------

Simple `validates` `presence` worked for me

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

This way, `Profile.create` will now fail. I have to use `user.create_profile` or associate a user before saving a `profile`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to ensure that the association is both present and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bank

  validates_associated :bank
  validates :bank, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if you could pass an additional option to `validates` like `valid: true` instead of having to call `validates_associated` separately.

Answer (score 6):

You can validate associations with [`validates_existence_of`](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence) (which is a plugin):

Example snippet from [this blog entry](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/7/14/validate-your-existence):

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  validates_existence_of :tag, :taggable

  belongs_to :user
  validates_existence_of :user, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Alternatively, you can use [`validates_associated`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated). As [*Faisal* notes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689888/rails-validate-presence-of-association#comment9489195_5690022) below the answer, `validates_associated` checks if the associated object is valid by running the associated class validations. It does **not** check for the presence. It's also important to note that a nil association is considered valid.