# Rails conditional validation based on a given Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I didn't define the problem correctly the first time. I tried to make a simple example and failed. Let's try again :)

I have an Address Model that validates the street, city, state, and zip attributes all exist. Then we have a Person Model that has a one to many relationship with Address. We have a student model but it DOESN'T inherit off person, it just has_one (I didn't completely understand how inheritance worked in ruby when I started). We have a Classroom model that also has_on person (again, not inherited.) So the issue is we want to require an address for the student, but not the Classroom. Hopefully this is a little more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: If you do understand how inheritance works now, why `Student` is still not inheriting from `Person` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - Validate Presence Of Association?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689888/rails-validate-presence-of-association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`validates`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) or [`validates_presence_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of) in only your `Student` model.

```
class Person
  has_many :addresses
end

class Student < Person
  validates :addresses, :presence => true
end

class Teacher < Person
end
```

Comment: After thinking about it, I could have another model that doesn't validate address and make the Classroom has_one of those. This is acceptable, just took me a lil while to wrap my head around it!