# Setting Rails Validations. Using two models in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a `Group` model and a `Message` model, each are HABTM. I'm trying to set a validation for my main form which is to send out a SMS to certain groups. Right now I have the body of message validated with `presence: true`, that is working fine but in my Group model I want to validate name to be present but how to I have them both validate when I'm calling a create method in the messages controller? I'll show my code for more clarification.

Here is `group.rb`

```
  class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :people
   has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
   validates :name, presence: true 
  end
```

Now `message.rb`

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

Here is my `message_controller.rb`

```
def create
@message = Message.create(message_params)
if @message.save
  run_at_time = @message.send_at.present? ? @message.send_at : Time.zone.now
  people = Person.in_groups(message_params[:group_ids])
  if people.any?
    people.each do |person|
      person.delay(run_at: run_at_time).send_message(@message.body)
    end
    flash[:success] = "Messages on their way!"
  end
  redirect_to root_path
else
  render "new"
end
end
```

[image]

For more understanding I want my form to display "Groups can't be blank" as well as "body can't be blank". If nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `valid?` was the first thing that came to mind, but there is another way as well.

Model validations actually have built-in support for assoiations.

For example,

```
class Message
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  validates :groups, presence: true
end
```

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690040/2981429).

So this would cause `save` to fail if the message had no groups.

There's always another way - you can override `valid?`, which is called internally
by `save`. For example:

```
class Message
  def valid?(*args)
    original_result = super(*args)
    if self.groups.empty?
      self.errors_add(:groups, "cannot be empty")
      return false
    end
    return original_result
  end
end
```

This is largely the same thing accomplished by `validates :groups, presence: true`,
although I think `presence: true` will also verify that the foreign keys refer to
valid records (rather than just checking that any associated record exist).

Calling `valid?` has the side effect of loading up the `errors` object. For example:

```
  msg = Message.new
  msg.errors.full_messages # => []
  msg.valid? # => false
  msg.errors.full_messages # => ["Name cant be blank", "Groups cant be blank"]
  msg.save # => false
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate multiple models before saving or collect all errors, you could do it by using `model.valid?` method.
It will return true of false, depending on whether there are any errors. And errors will be added to `model.errors`.