# How can I validate a parent model, which uses accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association (`contact_details`) in my *Company* model and I want to validate the parent model. Note: I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for in my parent model.

**The basic rule:**

> the company must have at least one phone (phone is the kind of
>   contact_detail)

**The problem:**

> accepts_nested_attributes_for call destroy for child objects AFTER
>   validation of the parent object

so the user are able to delete a phone. Of course, later, when the user will try to edit a company without a phone, he/she will get an error (`The company must have at least one phone`).

**Company (Parent) model:**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  PHONES_NUMBER_MIN = 1

  attr_accessible :name, :contact_details_attributes, ...

  has_many :contact_details, :as => :contactable, :dependent => :destroy

  validate do |company|
    check_phones_number
  end

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_details, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank

  private

  def phones_number_valid?
    kind = ContactDetail::Kind.phone
    phones = contact_details.select { |cd| cd.kind_id == kind.id }
    phones.size >= PHONES_NUMBER_MIN
  end

  def check_phones_number
    unless phones_number_valid?
      errors.add(:base, :phones_too_short, :count => PHONES_NUMBER_MIN)
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

**ContactDetail (Child) model:**

```
class ContactDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :kind_id, :kind_value_source

  belongs_to :contactable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :kind

  validates :kind_value_source, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 255}

  ...
end
```

Note: I simplified the original version, so objective was clear to you. Here is the [gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/3103220).
By using the reject_if option I am able to forbid the deletion of all the phones. It is probably the best option by now. But I want to hear your opinions.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5144527/820520) and tried to apply the answer, but it didn't helped a lot. The same problem, as I described above. I've drawn a flowchart so you can see the trace, as I see it.
[image: flowchart]

How can I validate the parent model in such a case?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What problems exactly did you have with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5144827/357743) solution?

Comment: @KL-7 the same, as I described above. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question you referenced, you can get rid of the `reject_if` and modify the line in `phones_number_valid?`:

```
phones = contact_details.select { |cd| cd.kind_id == kind.id && !cd.marked_for_destruction? }
```

Comment: Thank you @tanzeeb-khalili! I completely stuck with this, but you found the acceptable solution.