# Validation on a has_many relationship in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Given that I have the next models:

user.rb

```
has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
has_many :sports, through: :favorites
```

sport.rb

```
has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :favorites
```

In the form for create a new user, there is a list of checkboxes of sports, and in the user validation I want to validate that at least one is selected.

I'm doing it like this:

In the user controller create action:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.sports << Sport.find(params[:sports]) unless params[:sports].nil?

if @user.save ...
```

In the user model

```
validate :user_must_select_sport

def user_must_select_sport
  if sports.empty?
    errors.add(:Sport, "You have to select at least 1 sport")
  end
end
```

And it's actually working, but I'm guessing that it has to be a better way of doing this. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use "validates_presence_of"

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sports
  validates_presence_of :sports
end
```

But there is a bug with it if you will use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `:allow_destroy => true`.

You can look into this : [Nested models and parent validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144527/nested-models-and-parent-validation)