# rails - unknown column on relationship between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, rspec3

The migration:

```
class CreateTableSalonWebProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :salon_web_profiles do |t|
      t.references :salon, null: false
      t.boolean :attendance_domicile, default: false
      t.boolean :parking_lot, default: false
      t.boolean :wifi, default: false
      t.boolean :physically_impaired_accessibility, default: false
      t.boolean :snack_bar, default: false
      t.boolean :parking_meter, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :salon_web_profiles, :salon_id, unique: true
    add_foreign_key :salon_web_profiles, :salons
  end
end
```

The Salon model:

```
class Salon < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_one :salon_web_profile, dependent: :destroy
...
end
```

The new model:

```
class SalonWebProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :salon

  validates_presence_of :salon
  validates_uniqueness_of :salon
end
```

The new RSpec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SalonWebProfile do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:salon) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:salon) }
end
```

The error:

```
2) SalonWebProfile should require salon to be set
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:salon) }

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'salon_web_profiles.salon' in 'where clause': SELECT  1 AS one FROM `salon_web_profiles`  WHERE `salon_web_profiles`.`salon` IS NULL LIMIT 1
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/abstract_adapter.rb:15:in `instrument'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:97:in `validation_errors'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:77:in `collect_messages'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:40:in `messages'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:48:in `has_messages?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:277:in `has_messages?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:273:in `errors_match?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:224:in `block in matches?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:220:in `each'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:220:in `none?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:220:in `matches?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/disallow_value_matcher.rb:16:in `matches?'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validation_matcher.rb:56:in `disallows_value_of'
     # /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb:126:in `matches?'
     # ./spec/models/salon_web_profile_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Unknown column 'salon_web_profiles.salon' in 'where clause'
     #   /home/belasis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@user/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
```

I can not understand what is going on. Isn't it supposed to translate to `salon_id` when searching in database?
The version of rails is 3.2.22.5 and the RSpec version is 3.7.

That error doesn't happen when I'm using `rails c` and trying to create/access the salon_web_profile from salon and vice-versa.

Comment: `salon` is the model, `salon_id` would be the attribute, no?. However if using Rails 3, the `belongs_to` relationship should be required by default (unless you specify other thing).

Comment: I thought the `validates_presence_of :salon` would check if the salon really exists and `validates_presece_of :salon_id` would check only if the number is present, not mattering if exits a salon with this id or not. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your associations and test seem to be correct. Are you sure your test database has `salon_id` field?

Comment: also can you try using `validates :salon, presence: true` instead of `validates_presence_of :salon` and see if it changes anything

Comment: Tried it. Nothing changed.

Comment: This works please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689888/rails-validate-presence-of-association). [Nested models and parent validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144527/nested-models-and-parent-validation) also explains it in better way

Comment: what version of, rails and rspec are you using?

Comment: It's in the main question. Rails: 3.2.22.5 and RSpec: 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try in rails test console i.e rails c test, if the same error occurs, then try running rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

Comment: Looking at the error message `salon_web_profiles` already exists, we can rule out the possibility of pending migrations. Also he has the references in the same migration file